# Cant convert csv.DictReader object from bytes to string

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

```
fields = cgi.FieldStorage()
s = fields.getvalue('s')
request = {
   's' : s,
   'f' : 'snl1d1t1c1p2ohgv',
   'e' : '.csv'
}
parms = urllib.parse.urlencode(request)
u=urllib.request.urlopen("http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=IBM&f=snl1d1t1c1p2ohgv&e=.csv"+parms)
reader=csv.DictReader(u['symbol','name','price','date','time','change','percent','open','high','low','volume'])
record=next(reader)
```

I get the following error: **_csv.Error: iterator should return strings, not bytes (did you open the file in text mode?)**

Any suggestions?

Comment: The title of this question should be locked by mods for historical value.

Comment: @hoodaticus, I totally agree :D

Comment: oh lol tru @hoodaticus